# How using permalinks tags ID in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How using permalinks tags ID in url wordpress

Example:

```
wordpress.com/tag_name
```

i will :

```
wordpress.com/tag_id
```

Comment: But this is not the URL??

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're asking but if you would like to change the structure of your permalinks, you would go to WP-Admin and then go to:

Settings > Permalinks

You may also want to check out [Yoast's WordPress SEO plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/) which gives you more control over your permalink structure.

Comment: Thank you, 
I want to change the link to tags url.

Comment: In that case, I would grab the Yoast plugin.  Also, you may want to read his full article on WP SEO, particularly on [how tags are weighed in SEO](http://yoast.com/articles/wordpress-seo/#tag-optimization), which is not much.

Comment: WordPress default ID does not support links!